# I can't understand this code snippet in C

Tags: c, code-snippets

I can't seem to understand why is this code printing 1 as an answer.
I'm in process of learning C and this is one the questions for a homework.
Can somebody please explain?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    int i,j;
    int **p = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
    p[0] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    p[1] = p[0];
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                    p[i][j] = i + j;
    printf("%d",p[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

In my opinion is should print 0, but it seems i'm wrong.

Comment: What *does* it return?

Comment: Note that `p[0][0]` and `p[1][0]` are the same object, because `p[1]` points to the same address as `p[0]`.

Comment: It returns the value 1.

Comment: I thought of that, but I can understand that p[1] points to p[0] but why is p[0] taking the value of p[1], that should happen if the code was p[0]=p[1]. Am I wrong?

Comment: i meant prints, sorry about that

Comment: @cstoica `p[0]` is not "taking" the value of `p[1]`. They are the same object.

Comment: Before trying to understand it, fix it: remove the `malloc` casts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting confused with the pointers. `p[0]` is a pointer to `int`, so is `p[1]`.

The code makes `p[0]` and `p[1]` point to the same address:

```
p[1] = p[0];
```

This has the effect that `p[i][j]` refers to the same object whether `i` is 0 or 1. The nested loops will access `p[0][0]` in the first place, setting it to 0, but then later `p[1][0]` (which is the same object as `p[0][0]` is accessed, which causes it to be assigned 1.

The key point here is that `p[0][0]` and `p[1][0]` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

`p[0]` and `p[1]` are both `int *` type (i.e. pointers). After

```
p[1] = p[0];
```

both `p[1]` and `p[0]` are pointing to the same address, which makes `p[0][0]` the same to `p[1][0]`. The value is determined by which update it last. And `p[1][0]` updates this value at last, which makes the final result is 1.

If you change your code to:

```
for(i = 1; i >= 0; i--)
    for(j = 1; j >= 0; j--)
        p[i][j] = i + j;
printf("%d",p[1][0]);
```

Guess what, it will print 0. Hope it helps.